# Pixelated box during scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I have a strange problem on a small page I made.

When the content extends the height of the browser and I scroll down fast, the pixelated box appears for a split of a second and then goes away.

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: No code = no idea...can you post some HTML/CSS? Even a link?

Comment: I GUESS Its not an issue related to code. its machine specific. i faced same problem when my computer ran out of memory ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is just Chrome's rendering engine being crap. For the supposed "fastest browser", it fails to render part of the page when scrolling consistently often.

That said, there are some factors involved in when it happens. Generally, it can occur when there's a lot of layout recalculation. This may happen if you have a large table with images loading in, as each image's load causes the table to recalculate. Additionally, JavaScript can often cause recalculation in the layout. And it all depends on how powerful your computer is and how busy it is with other tasks.

Comment: Why does it only happen for me tho? I don't see that box no matter how fast I scroll on any SO page :c

Comment: It can vary based on the page's content. I have an admin page on my site that lists every single Pokémon sprite in a big table, and that really hammers the engine, to the point where sometimes it can't even render the checkered squares and just gives gray. However your site seems quite simple. It's most likely something in your JavaScript is causing large amounts of recalculation in the layout.

Comment: YES! That is the answer! "It's most likely something in your JavaScript is causing large amounts of recalculation in the layout". Please edit it in the answer for future use!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a chrome issue. I'm noticing this on a lot of websites since I moved from Firefox to Chrome.